# Move one element before another with css/html

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to "move" one full width element that is below another one so that it appears to be above by only using CSS/HTML? (and not changing the markup order)

```
<div id="first">first</div>
<div id="second">second</div>

#first {…}
#second {…}
```

Desirable result:

```
second
first
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only if you know exact height of second element:

```css
#first {
    margin-top: 20px;
}

#second {
    top: 0;
    position: absolute;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9zmcnedy/

Comment: Wow, this was too easy. I actually do have the height of one of the elements. So I guess this is the correct answer for me.

Comment: not sure if it is a universal solution for different div sizes.

Answer (score 45):

You can use [CSS Flexible Boxes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Flexible_boxes) for this. Specifically the [`order`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/order) property.

In this example I've added width and background-color to help visualize. Please note that browser support for CSS flexible boxes is limited to modern browsers such as IE 10+, Chrome 21+, Firefox 20+ and may not work well in mobile browsers (especially older ones).

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#first {
  order: 2;
  
  width: 10em;
  margin-top: 1em;
  background-color: orange;
}
#second {
  order: 1;
  
  width: 10em;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div id=first>
    first
  </div>
  <div id=second>
    second
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I was afraid that flex box would be the answer, as I have to support a few of the older browsers also.

Comment: Flexbox is certainly the most flexible option, but as other answers suggest, there are other ways of doing this if the height of the blocks are known in advance.

Comment: I agree. This is probably the correct answer within a year. But for me now I will go with another answer as I have the height of one of the element.

Answer (score 1):

[**Js Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/victor_007/1fd4daq3/1/)

something like this

```
#first { position:relative; top:18px}
#second {position:relative; bottom:18px}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a work-around by using `position: absolute` but this has a drawback that the parent element will not stretch the height as the child container's (*first element*) height increase. (*To fix that you should use javascript*)

**CSS**

```
.container {
    border: 1px solid green;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}
#first {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
}
```

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/venkateshwar/4xayhv08/)**

Answer (score 0):

This a very old question but I needed it and stumbled on this simple solution.

Wrap the two columns in a div and set the style for the div as

`display: flex;`

`flex-direction: column-reverse;`

e.g.

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column-reverse;
}

<div class="container">
  <div>first</div>
  <div>second</div>
</div>
```